# ERROR PYTHON: name 'cairosvg' is not defined

Tags: python, canvasvg

I alredy have a problem.
Show cairosvg as undefined. I wish save Turtle object as png.
I already installed the canvasvg and cairosvg libraries, but even so I keep getting the error. I leave my code as a sample. Thank you

```
   from turtle import *
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
import canvasvg

from canvasvg import *
screen=Screen()
setup (640,520,0,0)
title("T")
tracer(0,0)
encendido='#51D1F6'
apagado='#922B3E'

pant=Turtle(visible=False)
pant.hideturtle()
pant.pensize(4)
pant.penup()
pant.goto(110,0)
pant.pendown()

pant.pendown()
pant.fillcolor(encendido)
pant.begin_fill()
pant.goto(-400,-180)
pant.goto(-400,-190)
pant.goto(-110,-190)
pant.end_fill()


Y=7
gb=Y*4

agua=Turtle(visible=False)
agua.pensize(4)
agua.penup()


agua.goto(110,-200)
agua.pendown()

agua.fillcolor(encendido)
agua.begin_fill()

agua.goto(110,-200+gb)
agua.penup()
agua.goto(-110,-200+gb)

agua.pendown()
agua.goto(-110,-200)
agua.goto(110,-200)
agua.end_fill()
update()

ts=getscreen().getcanvas()

tmpdir=tempfile.mkdtemp()
tmpfile=os.path.join(tmpdir,'tmp.svg')
canvasvg.saveall(tmpfile,ts)
name="image4.png"
with open(tmpfile) as svg_input, open(name, 'wb')as png_output:
    cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svg_input.read(),write_to=png_output)
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```

Comment: Well, the compiler is right, ``cairosvg`` is undefined. Did you forget ``import cairosvg`` at the top of your module?

Comment: Show now:
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e